# can not add python to the path of environment variable

Tags: python, node.js, path

I have the same old problem of python not being recognized and get this error in VS:

```
    [Running] python -u "c:\Users\Keram\Desktop\WEB\index.py"
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

the solution is said to be putting the path of the python file where it is installed in the PATH of the environment.

but I had the same issue with node.js and had to put its path as the environment variable path.

now if I add python's path, I would not have node.js.

what am I supposed to ?

Comment: Have you tried adding both in the PATH?
Can you provide info on your system settings (OS version..)? and how you set the env variable?

Comment: `PATH` can (and almost always should) contain multiple paths. Colon (`:`) is used to separate entries (semicolon `;` on windows, AFAIR, but not sure here).

Comment: thank you guys. the ; allowed me to put multiple paths and now I can use both python and node.js. @SUTerliakov, and arnino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set path for node and python both, it doesn't affect anything.

Just go to environment variables, click path, edit, and then add the path of python executable file.
Then just restart/reopen the terminal and check.

I had the issue with python where the name was **python3** not the **python**

Renaming solved that issue too.

Hope it helps.!